# Microsoft CRM QueryExpression in C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, query-expressions

i have code like below:

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
            query.EntityName = "new_callistyorder"; 
            ColumnSet col = new ColumnSet("new_nomororder","new_customer");
            query.ColumnSet = col;

            EntityCollection colect = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

            string str = string.Empty;
            foreach (Entity e in colect.Entities)
            {
                if(e.Contains("new_nomororder")){
                str = str + e.Attributes["new_nomororder"].ToString();
                }
            }
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(str);
```

Trough this code. I am able to get data from microsoft dynamic entity. 
Now, i want to get the data which have biggest id.
If in SQL Query, it would be looks something like this : "Select top 1 my_id from Account order by my_id desc".
How can i do that on queryexpression ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the order by using this:

```
query.AddOrder("my_id", OrderType.Descending);
```

and then getting the first element retrieved.

```
var entityCollection = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
if(entityCollection.Entities.Count<1)
{
    //perform some logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks marco, 

can i ask you one more question?
how can i check if queryexpression is contain a data or not.

I was figured to use "TotalRecordCount". Is that the true ways ?

Comment: After the execute of the retrieve, assuming you store your entities in a variable called retrievedEntities you can check the size of the collection with retrievedEntities.Entities.Count

Comment: i dont get it: 
`if (colect.TotalRecordCount < 1)
                {
                    entity["new_nomororder"] = "ODR-C7HI-001";
                }
                else
                {
                    string str = string.Empty;
                    foreach (Entity e in colect.Entities)
                    {
                        if (e.Contains("new_nomororder"))
                        {
                            str = str + e.Attributes["new_nomororder"].ToString();
                        }
                    }`
i want to set field with value if queryexpression dosn;t contain data

Comment: Modified the answer after your comment